# Using Selenium to extract web text

Tags: python, selenium, loops, web-scraping

Hi I am trying to loop through a series of websites with and use selenium to extract the PEGY ratio and put into a CSV file. I assume it is a minor issue. This is what I have:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = 'C:/webdrivers/chromedriver.exe', options=options)

#with open("tickers.txt") as f:
    #stocks = f.read().splitlines()

stocks = ['T', 'PBCT', 'MSFT', 'AAPL']

for link in stocks:
    browser.maximize_window()
    browser.get('https://www.bloomberg.com/quote/' + link + ':US')
    time.sleep(5)  # wait 5 seconds for the page to load the js
    pageSource = browser.page_source
    soup = BeautifulSoup(pageSource, 'html.parser')
    prices = soup.find_all(class_='fieldValue__2d582aa7')
    price = prices[0].text
    print(price)
```

output:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:/Users/Highf_000/PycharmProjects/StockScreener/Bot.py", line 85, in 
        price = prices[0].text
    IndexError: list index out of range

```
Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: `soup.find_all(class_='fieldValue__2d582aa7')` didn't find anything, so `prices` is an empty list. Thus index 0 of prices doesn't exist. Probably need a try/except to catch index errors.

Comment: I am confused this is the tag...<span class="fieldValue__2d582aa7">1.1425</span>

Comment: the classname looks generated, maybe to stop people from scraping it... there ARE better ways to get stock prices on the web too

Comment: recommendations and examples?

Comment: if you do `print(browser.page_source)` on this, you'll find that they are pulling a sneaky on us and that element isnt there.

Comment: do you need the current price now like 10-minute data or historical?

Comment: check out stooq: https://stooq.com/q/d/l/?s=msft.us this will download a huge csv btw

Comment: Hi Tenacious, I just want to the PEGY ratio or a website that can get me the PE ratio and Dividend yield. Could you write up and example?

Comment: For instance Tenacious, could you do an example on https://www.marketwatch.com/investing/stock/t and pull out the PE ratio, I will work on the yield afterwards. I am really trying to learn this better lol.